# How to execute another python script from your script and be able to debug?

Tags: python, debugging, command-line, runpy

You have wrapper python script that is calling another python script, currently using `os.system('python another.py some-params')`.

You want to be able to debug both scripts and if you use `os.system()` you'll loose the debugger, so it does make sense to load the second script using the same interpretor instead of starting another one.

`import` doesn't to the expected thing because it does not run the `__main__`.

Other variants, like `exec()` or `runpy` seams to miss the `argv` parameters.

What solution do you see for this issue?

I'm looking for a solution that does not require you to modify the `another.py` script. Probably this will require to modify the `sys.argv` before executing it.

Comment: In the non-solutions, you also have `execfile()`, which might be useful in other situations.

Comment: I forgot about `execfile()`, I will test if it does run the `__main__` or not, this being very important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the recommendation received from EOL, I made an extension to `execfile()` that does solve its limitations [execfile2()](http://github.com/ssbarnea/tendo/blob/master/tendo/execfile2.py)

Below is the code, but newer versions will be published [here](http://github.com/ssbarnea/tendo/blob/master/tendo/execfile2.py). It is backwards compatible with `execfile()`.

```
def execfile2(filename, _globals=dict(), _locals=dict(), cmd=None, quiet=False):
    _globals['__name__']='__main__'
    saved_argv = sys.argv # we save sys.argv
    if cmd:
    sys.argv=list([filename])
            if isinstance(cmd , list):
                sys.argv.append(cmd)
            else:
                sys.argv.extend(shlex.split(cmd))
    exit_code = 0
try:
        execfile(filename, _globals, _locals)
    except SystemExit as e:
        if isinstance(e.code , int):
            exit_code = e.code # this could be 0 if you do sys.exit(0)
        else:
            exit_code = 1
    except Exception:
        if not quiet:
            import traceback
            traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stderr)
        exit_code = 1
    finally:
        if cmd:
            sys.argv = saved_argv # we restore sys.argv
    return exit_code
```

Comment: Your line, `saved_argv = sys.argv # we save sys.argv` is incorrect. Maybe you mean to copy the list: `saved_argv = sys.argv[:]`

Answer (score 10):

So far I found a solution that works only with Python 2.7+ (runpy.run_path() was introduced in Python 2.7).

If you can find one that works with 2.6 (or even 2.5) you are welcome to post it.

```
import runpy, sys
saved_argv = sys.argv
... # patch sys.argv[1:] and load new command line parameters
# run_path() does change only sys.argv[0] but restores it
runpy.run_path('another.py', run_name="__main__")
sys.argv = saved_argv # restore sys.argv
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have control over `another.py`? It would be a good idea to change it and add a `main()` method. `Main()` can then be invoked `if __name__ == '__main__'`. This will alleviate your problems a great deal. It is also unit testing friendly.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the main block call a function. This way you will be able to call the same function when importing as a module.

```
def main():
    print "All start up commands"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```