# Run a script in Spyder directly from another script in Spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I have a Main script in Spyder that calls several functions contained in 6 different scripts (.py). I had to this way because the scripts are also used in different projects.

Currently, I have to run each script (containing several functions each) separately by hand, which is tiring, by clicking in the "green triangle" before launching the Main Script so that the functions contained in each script are stored in the working environment.

My question is: Would it be possible to automatically run each script directly from the Main Script and not running one after the another by hand?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. There is the built-in module [runpy](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/runpy.html).

Comment: I have just noticed there was a question asking more or the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657955/how-to-execute-another-python-script-from-your-script-and-be-able-to-debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
from filename import *
```

instead of

```
import filename
```

No .py extension in the import.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute an `import` statement, the source file being imported is executed. So, for example, if you have `thing.py` and you execute `import thing`, all the code in `thing.py` will be run.

Also, as noted in a comment by *Sven Krüger*: you can use `runpy.run_path`, which I think is overall a better solution than my original suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunately, It doesn't work, even though I have added the path of the file where the script is to the Pythonpath manager